# Why do I need to return null for functions with nullable return type?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I get a warning in this code:

```dart
Future<int?> foo() async {
  if (someCondition) return 42;
}
```

> This function has a nullable return type of 'FutureOr<int?>', but ends without returning a value.

I'm telling Dart that the Future may complete with a nullable type `int?`, so why is that I've to explicitly return `null` to get away with the warning?

Comment: I don't see the same warning for this code. What does your `analysis_options.yaml` look like?

Comment: @mmcdon20 I have `include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml` without any explicit linter rule.

Comment: do you have any explicit analyzer rules?

Comment: @mmcdon20 No, that was the only line there in the file. I didn't add any linter or analyzer rule myself anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then, sorry. I have a project open with the same `analysis_options.yaml` settings and I am not seeing this warning.

Comment: @mmcdon20 I just created a new Flutter project and I'm seeing the same warning there. So, you must have silenced it somewhere in your project.

Comment: no I also created a brand new flutter project to test this. Maybe we have different versions of flutter/dart? I have `Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable`, `Tools • Dart 2.15.1` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241592/discussion-between-idecode-and-mmcdon20).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error.  Warnings are for things that are technically legal but very likely are programming mistakes.  It's much more likely that someone writing that code forgot to handle a code path than it is that they intentionally wanted an implicit `return null`.  An explicit `return null` additionally makes intent clear and thus is more readable.